# "Use of undeclared identifier 'Braintree'" error after manual Braintree integration without using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, braintree

I am getting the following error when calling `[Braintree braintreeWithClientToken`.

> ViewController.m:21:27: Use of undeclared identifier 'Braintree'

I followed the [Manual Integration Without CocoaPods](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/Docs/Manual%20Integration.md) guide to add Braintree to a new Objective-C project.

### Solution - building `Braintree.framework`

I have managed to build a Braintree.framework that can easily be used in iOS apps, Objective-C or Swift.

Instructions are there:

https://github.com/exchangegroup/braintree-framework-builder

Comment: I am facing same error. Did you find any solution?

Comment: It looks like we [resolved this on GitHub](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/111). Feel free to post your solution as an answer here for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Here's a PR which fixes this error in your Demo: https://github.com/exchangegroup/brain-tree-manual-setup-error-four/pull/1</s>

Here's a PR which fixes this error in your newer Demo: https://github.com/exchangegroup/braintree-manul-setup-ten/pull/1

Unfortunately, the `#import` statements using `<angled>` includes had to be replaced with `"quotes"` instead. While non-ideal, this was a straightforward operation by using a find-and-replace regex: `<Braintree/(.*)>` -> `"$1"`

If you're doing a new integration, Braintree recommends [using CocoaPods instead](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/ios+ruby/start/hello-client#install). Let us know if there's a reason CocoaPods won't work for your use case.

Hope this helps :)